# PHP IF si se dan tres condiciones buscador no logro filtar por precios

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sigo con problemas, perdonen mi ignorancia, ya intente por todos los medios y no logro filtrar por el rango de precios:

**Este es el código `Ajax` que esta en la home**

```
 <script>

    function filterProducts() {

    var marcas = $('.valor_marca').val();

    var cat = $('.valor_cat').val();

    var price_range = $('.price_range').val();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',

        url: 'buscar.php',

        data: 'price_range='+price_range+'&marcas='+marcas+'&cat='+cat,

        beforeSend: function () {

            $('.container').css("opacity", ".5");

        },

        success: function (html) {

            $('#productContainer').html(html);

            $('.container').css("opacity", "");

        }

    });

}

</script>
```

**este es el codigo de la pagina buscar.php**

```
<?php

require("php/db.php");

///////// parametros que recibo del formulario /////////////

$constante ="";

$marcas = $_POST['marcas'];

$cat = $_POST['cat'];

$priceRange = $_POST['price_range'];


if(!empty($_POST['price_range']))

    {

    $priceRangeArr = explode(',', $priceRange);

    $constante = "WHERE precio_pro BETWEEN '".$priceRangeArr[0]."' AND '".$priceRangeArr[1]."'";

    }

if(!empty($_POST["cat"]) && !empty($_POST["marcas"])) 

    {

    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat AND marca_pro = $marcas"; 

    }

else if(!empty($_POST['cat']))

    {

    $constante = "WHERE cat_pro = $cat";

    }

else if(!empty($_POST['marcas']))

    {

    $constante = "WHERE marca_pro = $marcas";

    }

else{

    $constante = "";

}

////////// condiciones ///////////

$consulta1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM productos Left Join marcas ON productos.marca_pro = marcas.id_marcas Left Join combo ON productos.combo_pro = combo.id_combo $constante");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

echo "<!-- combo --><div class=\"card mb-4\">


    <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"images/combos/".$row['foto_combo']."\" alt=\"Card image cap\">

    <div class=\"card-body\">

    <div class=\"row\">


<!-- productos --><div class=\"col-xl-6 col-lg-6\">

    <div class=\"marca\">".$row['nombre_marcas']."</div>

    <div class=\"desc\">".$row['nombre_pro']."</div>

    <div class=\"precio\">$ ".$row['precio_pro']."</div>

</div><!-- end productos -->

</div>

    </div>

  </div><!-- end combo -->";

}

?>
```

Comment: edité tu pregunta, pues es código php y js; entonces no veo por que poner la etiqueta de Java

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Pusiste el código Ajax, pusiste el código PHP, pero no dijiste cuál es el problema. El título no basta para explicar un problema.

Comment: @Ricardo, por que la etiqueta Java, si no ocupa ese lenguaje?

Comment: Tienes razón @shadow, se me pasó quitarlas, creo que ambos estábamos editando al mismo tiempo, y no es que yo haya vuelto a poner las que tu quitaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto que no puedes filtrar por precio, estas sobrescribiendo todo el tiempo su valor.

Prueba así:

```
$constante = ' WHERE 1 ';

if(!empty($_POST['price_range']))  {
    $priceRangeArr = explode(',', $priceRange);
    $constante .= " AND precio_pro BETWEEN '".$priceRangeArr[0]."' AND '".$priceRangeArr[1]."'";
}

if(!empty($_POST['cat'])) {
    $constante .= " AND cat_pro = $cat";
}

if(!empty($_POST['marcas'])){
    $constante .= " AND marca_pro = $marcas";
}
```

De esta forma evitas los `else`, no es practico escribir código para cada una de las posibilidades, imagina cuando tengas 20 campos!!!

Empezamos dando un valor por defecto que sea neutro, en este caso `WHERE 1`, que es es valido para cualquier valor (es decir actúa como si no hubiera `WHERE`).

Y ahora solo iremos concatenando más valores del filtrado según existan, en caso contrario no añadimos nada.

Al final tenemos en la cadena `$constante` el valor correcto según lleguen o no parámetros.